# JQuery to show a div with same class

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I made a simple jQuery to show a div with same class when clicking a link by referring to following code at http://jsfiddle.net/6GvE6/6/. (You can see the code modified by me at http://jsfiddle.net/UpX3L/1717/)

```
$('[id^="wrapper"]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.wrap > div').hide();

    $('.'+ this.id).show();
});
```

Both seem to work in JSFiddle, but when I tried to use them in my WordPress blog, they did not work.

Comment: try using event delegation

Comment: try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kuLzc5cn/1/ - there are some logging see whether those are appearing in the console

Comment: Use Firebug or the console on your WordPress page to check for JavaScript errors/issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes inspect your code. 
Check in console, if it is '$ is undefined' error.

Replace '$' with 'jQuery' in your code.

This is the standard for WordPress

Comment: Hi vijay, Thanks for your help. It works when I replaced '$' with 'jQuery'. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi vijay. Is there a way to hide the sub-div when clicking the (parent) link again?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final version:

```
$('[id^="wrapper"]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = this.id;
    $('.wrap > div').each(function() {
        if(!$(this).hasClass(id)) {
            $(this).hide();
        }
    });

    $('.'+ this.id).slideToggle('slow');
});
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UpX3L/1722/)